# Cannot set attributeBindings to property on View's ObjectController in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I managed to set the attributeBinding to the controller context through my handlebars template:

```
<li {{bindAttr class="view.controller.isSelected:active:"}}>
    <a href="#" {{action "toggleSelected"}}>{{view.controller.title}}</a>
</li>
```

Which is called within an each group like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
    {{#each skill in controller}}
        {{view App.SkillView}}
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

But I found EmberJS was adding divs around each view which was causing problems with my CSS so I removed the `li` tags from the template and set the tagName in the `SkillView` and attempted attributeBinding through the JS object which adds an li DOM element where I want it but the attributeBindings I was using doesn't seem to work:

```
App.SkillView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'skill',
    tagName: 'li',
    attributeBindings: ['controller.isSelected:active:']
});
```

Nor does this:

```
App.SkillView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'skill',
    tagName: 'li',
    attributeBindings: ['view.controller.isSelected:active:']
});
```

Nor this:

```
App.SkillView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'skill',
    tagName: 'li',
    attributeBindings: ['isSelected:active:']
});
```

How do I reference the controller from within the view in the context of a view binding string? What am I doing on the Handlebars Template I am not doing in the View code?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out I should have been using classNameBindings instead of attributeBindings. The following worked:

```
App.SkillView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'skill',
    tagName: 'li',
    classNameBindings: ['controller.isSelected:active:']
});
```